# In python, how to convert specific values in a list to different values based on special conditions

Tags: list, input, replace

I am trying to write a program that converts a percentage received in a class into a GPA format then eventually find the overall GPA. I want it to first prompt the user to input the amount of classes, then input the percentages. I am running into some trouble getting the program to convert the percentage into the GPA format (90 or greater equals 4, 80 to 89 equals 3, ect...). This is what I have so far

```
class_number = int(raw_input("How many classes do you have? "))
total_grade = list((raw_input("Enter Percentage: ")) for i in range(class_number))

a = total_grade

def alter(x):
   if x >= 90:
    return 4
   elif x >= 80:
    return 3
a = map(alter,a)

print a
```

The problem is that this only seems to output 4s no matter the original percentage.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `x` is actually a string. I think a string will always be greater than a number. You need to convert each item in `total_grade` to an int:

```
total_grade = list(int(raw_input("Enter Percentage: ")) for i in range(class_number))
```

Also, you can just use a list comprehension:

```
total_grade = [int(raw_input("Enter Percentage: ")) for i in range(class_number)]
```